# run a program avoiding overwriting output

Tags: bash

I have 1000 inputs for a program which I have no control on the output

I can run the program over each file like below. So this program goes take the input file which is like input1, input2 and input3, then run my program and save several outputs there but each time overwrite the outputs to the previous

```
for i in {1..3}; do
myprogram input"$i" 
done
```

I thought I generate 3 folders and put the input files there then I run the program so maybe the program write the output there, but still not successful.

```
for i in {1..3}; do
myprogram "$i"/input"$i" 
done
```

Basically I want to exe the program that save the output in each file and then go to another folder .

Is there anyway to cope with this?

Thanks

Comment: Where is the output stored? You can move each input file to a different folder?

Comment: @Kamil Cuk they are several outputs in the same directory that I execute the .sh . Yes I can move each input file into a different folder. In my second attempt , I made 3 folders and I put each input in one then I execute the file but still the program overwrite the outputs

Comment: There is nothign in your shown code that has anything to do with output.  Post teh code to `myprogram`

Comment: @ivanivan my program is a commercial code , I don't have any access into it or over it. This is the biggest problem I have. If I had a output names T, I could simply write it `T$i`and it would call it that way, the problem is that I don't have power on the output and I was wishing that somehow I could execute my code to save the output inside each of those folders ?

Comment: Does the program always output to the same file name, or can you specify that on the command line?

Comment: @ivanivan exactly the same file names . that is why it overwrite them . if that matters I can tell the names ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is overwriting the input file as indicated in your comment, you can do save the original input file by copying and renaming/moving then calling the program.  Then if you really want them in a subdirectory, make a directory, and move the input and/or output file(s).

```
for i in {1..3}
do
  cp infile$i outfile$i
  ./myprogram outfile$i
  mkdir programRun-$i 
  mv infile$i outfile$i programRun-$i
done
```

If it is leaving the input file alone, and just outputs to a consistent file name, then something like

```
for i in {1..3}
do
  ./myprogram infile$i
  mkdir programRun-$i 
  mv outfile programRun-$i/outfile-$i
done
```

Note that in either case, I'd consider using a different variable than `$i` to identify which run of the program - perhaps a time/date in YYYMMDDHHMMSS form, or just a unix timestamp.  Just for organization purposes, and that way all output files from a given run are together... but whatever fits your needs.

Comment: here I should have the names of outputs in order to move them in to that directory , lets say my outputs are "X.tgg" , "B.Tbb" , "N.Ynh", "K.tre" etc. would you mention them after mv?

Comment: @NikolasService - yes, if there are always the same multiple output files then move them all

Answer (score 0):

If the myprogram is always creating the same file names then you could move them off before executing the next loop iteration.  In this example if the output is files called out*.txt .

```
for i in {1..3}; do ./myprogram input"$i"; mkdir output"$i"; mv out*.txt output"$i"/; done
```

If the file names created differ you could create new directories and cd into those prior to executing the application.

```
 for i in {1..3}; do mkdir output"$i"; cd output"$i"; ../myprogram ../input"$i"; cd ..; done
```